# probability of single event given probability of multiple events

Tags: probability

If the probability of an unfair coin landing heads 2 times out of 3 tosses is (0.9^2)(0.1)(3) find the probability of heads, i.e., the probability of success.

--I'm having trouble approaching this question.

Comment: There are in fact two solutions in the interval $[0,1]$.  Do you want the easy one or the slightly more complicated one?

Comment: Should $0.92$ not be $0.9^2$ ?

Comment: Henry, I would love to see both of your solutions. Peter, you are right, it is in-fact supposed to say .9^2 I apologize for the typo.

Comment: @JonW: I presented the second solution in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we denote the probability of heads by $p$, then the probability of two heads out of three tosses is

$$
P = \binom{3}{2}p^2(1-p) = 3p^2(1-p)
$$

We wish to set this equal to $3(9/10)^2(1/10)$.  One way is to do this by inspection, which yields an obvious value of $p = \, ?$

As Henry points out in the comments, however, there is another solution, which isn't surprising since the equation

$$
3p^2(1-p) = 3\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)
          = \frac{243}{1000}
$$

is a cubic and may have as many as three solutions.  However, to correspond to a physical solution, we must also impose the constraint $0 \leq p \leq 1$.  If we add $3p^2(1-p)$ to both sides and expand, we get

$$
3p^3-3p^2+\frac{243}{1000} = 0
$$

Cubics are, in general, a messy matter to solve, but in this case, we are fortunate to already know a value by inspection.  Call this value $p_1$, and then to find other solutions, we assert $p \not= p_1$, so we can divide both sides by $p-p_1$:

$$
\frac{3p^3-3p^2+\frac{243}{1000}}{p-p_1} = 0
$$

Carrying out this division yields

$$
3p^2-\frac{3}{10}p-\frac{27}{100} = 0
$$

(Technically, I've given away $p_1$ by giving the result of the division, but I think that won't be much of a spoiler.)  This can be solved by means of the quadratic formula, and yields the other two roots:

$$
p_{2,3} = \frac{-10 \pm \sqrt{100-4(100)(9)}}{200}
        = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{37}}{20}
$$

Of these $p_3 < 0$ and therefore can't be used as a physical solution, but $p_2 \doteq 0.35414$ and therefore satisfies the conditions.

In fact, since $3p^2(1-p)$ has a simple maximum at $p = 2/3$ and is otherwise increasing in $(0, 2/3)$ and decreasing in $(2/3, 1)$, it follows that *any* coin (except for one with a $p = 2/3$ probability of falling heads) has a "twin" that produces two heads in three flips with the same probability.  If one coin comes up heads with probability $p_1$, the other comes up heads with probability

$$
p_2 = \frac{1-q+\sqrt{1+2q-3q^2}}{2}
$$

Note that this other coin is a "twin" only in the sense of having the same probability of generating two heads in three tosses, and otherwise has a much different distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the outstanding explanation. Up in part one of your response, what is it that you are implying by stating "...which yields an obvious value of p=?"

Comment: He wants you to think for your self and find p

Comment: Thanks Marco, I guess I should have realized that. I have come to the conclusion that p must be equal to .9

Comment: Certainly the value of $p = 0.9$ works, and it is the value one can quickly obtain by inspection.  However, Henry's comment suggests (and my answer is intended to illustrate) that there is another solution, and in fact, there is always another solution, unless the the probability of heads is $2/3$.

Answer (score 2):

$\binom{3}{2}\cdot 0.9^2\cdot 0.1$ is the probability of two successes (and one failure) in a *Binomial Distribution* with parameters $n=$what? and $p=$what?.

Comment: Graham, I am not sure what you mean by n =? and p =?. This notation has not been used in my readings of binomial distribution.

Comment: must be p = .9 and n = 3 and k = 2 correct?

Comment: @JonW $n = $ what? and $p=$ what?